# Collisions in a Zobrist transposition table

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

I`m creating a tictactoe AI and want to allow fields bigger than 5x5 but for this I need a Transposition Table. I created a table classed based on Zobrist Hashing but I get hash collisions which lead to AI loosing. Is there a way to remove the collisions without storing the field's state?

```
struct Entry
{
    Entry(std::pair<int, int> _scoreMove, int _alpha, int _beta, unsigned long long _hash) : scoreMove(_scoreMove), alpha(_alpha), beta(_beta), hash(_hash) {}
    std::pair<int, int> scoreMove;
    int alpha;
    int beta;
    unsigned long long hash;

    bool operator == (const Entry& lhs) { return this->hash == lhs.hash && this->alpha == lhs.alpha && this->beta == lhs.beta && this->scoreMove == lhs.scoreMove; }
};
class TranspositionTable
{
public:
    TranspositionTable() = delete;
    TranspositionTable(std::shared_ptr<Field> f);


    unsigned long long calculateHash();
    inline unsigned long long recalculateHash(unsigned long long hash, int index) { return hash ^ zobristKeys[getKeyIndex(index)]; }
    Entry& operator[](int h) { 
        if (entries[h % entries.size()].hash == h) return entries[h % entries.size()]; 
        else return nullEntry; }
    void placeEntry(unsigned long long hash, std::pair<int, int> scoreMove, int alpha, int beta);
public:
    Entry nullEntry = Entry({ 0, -2 }, INT_MIN, INT_MAX, 0);
private:
    int getKeyIndex(int i) { int index = 2 * i; index += (*field)[i] == player::AI ? 1 : 0; return index; }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Field> field;
    std::vector<int> zobristKeys;
    std::vector<Entry> entries;

};
```

and the cpp

```
TranspositionTable::TranspositionTable(std::shared_ptr<Field> f) : field(f)
{
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long long> distribution;
    zobristKeys.reserve(2 * field->size());
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * field->size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned long long rand = distribution(generator);
        while (std::find(zobristKeys.begin(), zobristKeys.end(), rand) != zobristKeys.end())
            rand = distribution(generator);
        zobristKeys.emplace_back(rand);
    }
    entries.reserve(pow(2, field->size()));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pow(2, field->size()); i++)
        entries.emplace_back(nullEntry);
}

unsigned long long TranspositionTable::calculateHash()
{
    unsigned long long hash = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < field->size(); i++)
        if ((*field)[i] != player::None)
            hash ^= zobristKeys[getKeyIndex(i)];
    return hash;
}

void TranspositionTable::placeEntry(unsigned long long hash, std::pair<int, int> scoreMove, int alpha, int beta)
{
    Entry e(scoreMove, alpha, beta, hash);
    entries[hash % entries.size()] = e;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using a power of 2 as the hash table size. That doesn't work well with Zobrist hashing, since essentially you're throwing away the upper bits of the hash value. For example, if `field->size()` is 25, then you are only using 25 bits out of the 64 bits of the hash value. Computing the hash modulo a large prime is a better solution.

Comment: That still won't eliminate all collisions. You can resolve some of the collisions by keeping the full 64 bit hash as part of the hash table entry. Use the full 64 bit hash as part of the [collision resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) scheme of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions, and then more context.

1. Don't store entries at the bottom of the tree.
2. Don't make your transposition table a power of 2.
3. Compute the hash incrementally. (Will be faster but won't avoid collisions.)

To review, one good way to implement a Zobrist hash for a game like 5x5 TicTacToe is to build a table of values for every location for each single piece. So, 25 entries in the table for all the possible X locations and 25 entries in a different table for all possible O locations. These table entries are 64-bit random numbers.

You are doing this in your transposition table, but this probably shouldn't be part of the transposition table code. If you want to use the transposition table for another game, you'll have to re-write this portion. But, if the hash computation is part of the game state, you can just pass in the hash and use it. Also, you are re-doing the computation each time you compute a hash, which is unnecessary - you can do it incrementally.

If you store the hash in the state, when you apply actions in the game you incrementally compute the hash and maintain it at all times. The hash can start at 0 at the root (no pieces in any location). When you apply an action, you XOR into the hash the table entry for the move being made. When you undo actions, you also XOR the table value for the move being undone, effectively removing it from the hash.

So, instead of doing this inside `calculateHash` I'd have something like this in when you apply (or undo) an action:

```
void Apply(act a, state &s)
{
    s.hash = s.hash^zobrist[a.player][a.location];
    ....
}
```

Now, when you want to store a state in your transposition table, you can use the hash directly. As suggested in the comments to your question, you shouldn't make your table size a power of 2. A prime number is a good choice, because it is likely to distribute your keys more evenly across the hash table. But, even using `pow(2, field->size())-1` is probably going to work better.

Finally, you probably want to avoid using your transposition table in the lower portions of your search tree. There is no point looking up a value in the transposition table 1-ply from a leaf, where it would be cheaper to just compute the exact value of the state through a small search. (Your memory accesses to the table will be random, and thus will incur frequent cache misses.) Not only will this make your code faster, the bulk of states explored are near the leaves, so this will drastically reduce the number of entries used, and thus will help avoid collisions as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I do have a recalculateHash function that == to your apply function. So there are no ways to eliminate collisions using Zobrist keys? What if there is a hash collision between the winning state and a loosing state? The AI will then make a move that will lead to immediete loose(this happend a lot of times in my case with the poor table size)

Comment: If you store the hash in the state and verify that the hash is different you will avoid many more collisions. But, how many states are you seeing in your full search? How many are at least 2-ply from the leaves? Have you tried writing all terminate states to a file during search and then checking their hashes for collisions later to verify whether this is happening?